# Why does the wizard form header change when the isxdl plugin downloading page is shown?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using the following lines to change the `MainPanel` color and `WizardSmallBitmapImage` image:

```
[Setup]
WizardSmallImageFile=MyFile.bmp

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.MainPanel.Color := $00FFDBBF;
end;
```

In my setup I'm using the [`isxdl`](http://sourceforge.net/p/istool/code/HEAD/tree/isxdl/) plugin for downloading prerequisites and the problem is that when its downloading progress page is shown, the `MainPanel` and `WizardSmallBitmapImage` components change their look back to the default as I've tried to illustrate on this picture:

[image]

Why does the wizard form header change when the isxdl plugin downloading page is shown and how to keep the modified look of the page header even for this page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of this problem lies deep inside the [`isxdl`](http://sourceforge.net/p/istool/code/HEAD/tree/isxdl/) plugin which [`draws its own header`](http://sourceforge.net/p/istool/code/HEAD/tree/isxdl/trunk/source/DownloadDlg.cpp#l71), so what you see on that page is not Inno Setup's `MainPanel` and `WizardSmallBitmapImage` but elements drawn by that plugin, hardcoded in its source code.

In my view it would be unecessarily overcomplicated (if even possible) to intercept that plugin's window proc for overdrawing those elements with their actual look (in a response to the `WM_PAINT` message), so I would suggest you either building your own version of that plugin, or switching to a different plugin, e.g. [`Inno Download Plugin`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-download-plugin/) which is also easy to use and which doesn't break the wizard look.

Comment: This code sample is working for Other Window. Attached window created using CreateOutputProgressPage and not apply to this window.

Comment: Assuming that by *"other window"* you mean other page, I cannot reproduce any problem and after a quick look in the source I doubt I would be able to. The `TOutputProgressWizardPage` page does nothing with that panel. Maybe it's time for you to show us a minimalistic code, where we could reproduce your issue. Oh, but now looking on that image, you are using some skinning library, right ? Then I'm giving up...

Comment: you can download Skinning theme from below link and easyly Apply.


https://www.dropbox.com/s/wuab3nz6o06msvg/ISSkin.dll
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhijgj9fq33ikol/Office2007.cjstyles


[Code]
procedure LoadSkin(lpszPath: String; lpszIniFileName: String); external 'LoadSkin@files:isskin.dll stdcall';

Function InitializeSetup() : boolean;
 begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Office2007.cjstyles');
  LoadSkin(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Office2007.cjstyles'), '');

Comment: Even when using ISSkin plugin I cannot reproduce any problem. The main panel color remains unchanged on a `TOutputProgressWizardPage` that I've created. To help you, I will need to see a minimalistic code, that will show the issue you're having.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jjt5s0gofnqkzgx/DemoScript.zip  i prepared small demo script. you can download from this link. when setup download .net framework from web at that time white top bar window displayed.

Comment: I've completely rephrased your question. Could you please make a review (you can use rollback to revert it back) and check if I understood your situation correctly ?

Comment: do you have any other plugin to download dependencies / file ?

Comment: I would recommend you [`IDP`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-download-plugin/) plugin which is also very easy to use, supports Unicode and ANSI Inno Setup, 3 network protocols and what will be most interesting for you, it doesn't break the page look by drawing own elements.